# React Navigation: How to hide specific tab from bottomTabNavigator based on logged in user role?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a bottom tab navigator in my screen with this structure (`HomeScreen.js`):

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeStack,
    Transactions: TransactionsTab,
    Customers: CustomersStack,
    Settings: SettingsTab
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `home`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Transactions') {
          iconName = `file-text`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Customers') {
          iconName = `users`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `settings`;
        }

        return <Feather name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      }
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#C62828',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      style: {
        borderTopWidth: 0,
        elevation: 8,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF'
      }
    }
  }
);
```

In my `LoginScreen.js` (if user is authenticated):

```
resetTo(navigation, 'home');

export function resetTo(navigation, routeName) {
  const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName })]
  });
  navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
}
```

And I want to hide **Customer** tab if the logged in user has no privilege to access this tab, so the number of tabs would be only 3. Otherwise, it would be 4. How can I tell the navigator from my login screen about the user privileges so the navigator can show the correct tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can provide us with your login screen code too I can provide more help, based on your sample code it seems you are using "react-navigation". In your login screen do this

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {loginStatus: status});
```

Then in your HomeScreen.js in constructor you can read the variable like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.status=props.navigation.getParam('loginStatus');
}
```

and last you can use this variable to now show the customer tab like this

```
const test = this.status ? {Home: {screen: MainActivity}} : null;
{
   test,
   Transactions: TransactionsTab,
   Customers: CustomersStack,
   Settings: SettingsTab
}
```

Of course if you have many if this parameter passing between your Screens you can use a framework like Redux or Redux-Saga that will centralize your 'state' throughout your code

Comment: Hi @dna-h, I just updated my question with providing `resetTo` function. Yes, I use react-navigation.

Comment: great, in StackActions you can pass data like this 
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName, params:{foo: 'bar' }})]
  });
then in HomeScreen do this
    this.status=props.navigation.getParam('foo');

Comment: @dna-h I can't pass props (which is got from navigation params) to my navigator (which is not a React component).

Comment: yeah, your syntax confused me a little bit too. I edited your syntax to some extend and found a working solution for you. check this https://pastebin.com/riWwTSfd . line 82 helps you to see if parameter is received correctly. The idea in your Login.js is the same just send data using NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName, params:{foo: 'bar' }})

Comment: @dna-h I solved using this way, but now I can't reset the navigation across the stack navigator.

Comment: your normal StackActions.reset(); should be working, these new codes just meant to resolve showing of 3rd tab. What is the problem that you can't reset navigation?

Comment: @dna-h I post it as new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946507/react-navigation-how-to-go-back-to-a-screen-in-another-stack-from-a-stack