# How to limit the tabs according to user roles?

Tags: react-native, tabs, roles

Basically from the picture, we have Home, Listing, Calendar and Profile respectively.

[Click here for pic!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMwBO.jpg)
Assuming that this is an application for student and teacher only,

if I want teacher role to be able to display the 4 tabs as shown and for student, only Home, Calendar and Profile only upon log in... How do i go upon this?

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-home' : 'md-home'}
    />
  ),
};

const CalendarStack = createStackNavigator({
  Calendar: CalendarScreen,
});

CalendarStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Calendar',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-calendar' : 'md-calendar'}
    />
  ),
};

const ListingStack = createStackNavigator({
  Listing: ListingScreen,
});

ListingStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Listing',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-paper' : 'md-paper'}
    />
  ),
};

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
});

ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-today' : 'md-today'}
    />
  ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  ListingStack,
  CalendarStack,
  ProfileStack
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Navigation: How to hide specific tab from bottomTabNavigator based on logged in user role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941099/react-navigation-how-to-hide-specific-tab-from-bottomtabnavigator-based-on-logg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put a basic if condition to change the `TabNavigator` like follows

```
let bottomTabNavigator = null

if (userRole === "admin") {
    bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
       HomeStack,
       ListingStack,
       CalendarStack,
       ProfileStack
    });
} else {
    bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
       HomeStack,
       CalendarStack,
       ProfileStack
    });
}
export default bottomTapNavigator
```

Comment: I see I see. I think it kinda work. But just asking, how do i get the firebase authenticated user from other screen then?

Comment: You can add middleware kind of thing. You will be able to get the firebase auth users data in a variable right? using that you can do it I guess..